# To implement navigation guards using autoroute flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, auto-route

I'm trying to learn to [auto_route](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#route-guards) and its features. Now I'm stuck in navigation guards, I'm using Riverpod for state management.
Here I wanted to implement an authGuard for navigating users to different screens if user is not logged in.

```
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {
 @override
 List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
    AutoRoute(
      page: SplashRoute.page,
      initial: true,
    ),
    AutoRoute(page: StarredRepoRoute.page, guards: [AuthGuard]),
    AutoRoute(page: SignInRoute.page),
    AutoRoute(page: AuthorizationRoute.page),
  ];

bool isInitialRoute() {
return false;
}
}
```

The above-pasted code is the AppRouter and you can see that I have mentioned guards for StarredRepoRoute and the guard is AuthGuard.

```
class AuthGuard extends AutoRouteGuard {
 final Ref _ref;
 AuthGuard(this._ref);
 @override
 void onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) async {
   final authState = _ref.watch(authNotifierProvider);
   authState.maybeMap(
    orElse: () => false,
    authenticated: (_) => true,
  );
 }
}
```

If the onNavigation return true it will navigate to StarredRepoRoute. I also settled up an authGuardProvider for it.

```
final authGuardProvider = Provider<AuthGuard>((ref) {
  return AuthGuard(ref);
});
```

But the issue is that when I refer to
guard as AuthGuard as appRouter it says

[image]

Is there anything I miss or is there any other way to implement it?

Comment: Here found any working solution??

Answer (score 1):

RiverPod already serves as replacement for dependency injection I think you don't need to add another one. Have you tried passing the WidgetRef through AppRoute constructor?

```
class MainApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
        routerConfig: AppRouter(ref).config(),
    ...
```

on the AppRoute file do:

```
@AutoRouterConfig()
class AppRouter extends $AppRouter {
  WidgetRef ref;

  AppRouter(this.ref) : super();

  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
        AutoRoute(path: '/', page: LoginRoute.page),
        AutoRoute(
          path: '/main-nav',
          page: MainNav.page,
          guards: [AuthGuard(ref)],
        ),
      ];
}
```

and finally on the GuardRoute do:

```
class AuthGuard extends AutoRouteGuard {
  final WidgetRef ref;

  AuthGuard(this.ref);

  @override
  void onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) async {
    UserDTO? user = ref.watch(userServiceProvider.notifier).getLoggedUser();

    if (user != null) {
      resolver.next(true);
    } else {
      router.push(const LoginRoute());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We assign guards to route by doing the below:

```
AutoRoute(page: StarredRepoRoute.page, guards: [AuthGuard()]),
```

and not

```
AutoRoute(page: StarredRepoRoute.page, guards: [AuthGuard]),
```

Comment: but how can I pass ref as an argument to authguard

Comment: Use a consumer and pass the ref from it as a parameter to your authguard

Comment: What do you mean by consumer, I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue with [GetIt Dependency Injection](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it).

Instead of `Ref` the AuthGuard depends on `ProviderContainer`:

```
class AuthGuard extends AutoRouteGuard {
  final ProviderContainer providerContainer;
 AuthGuard(this.providerContainer);
 @override
 void onNavigation(NavigationResolver resolver, StackRouter router) async {
   final authState = providerContainer.read(authNotifierProvider);
   authState.maybeMap(
    orElse: () => false,
    authenticated: (_) => true,
  );
 }
}
```

The providerContainer can be a static variable somewhere in your project and should be explicitly set in the `UncontrolledProviderScope`:

```
final ProviderContainer providerContainer = ProviderContainer()
   
...

  runApp(UncontrolledProviderScope(
    container: providerContainer,
    child: const App(),
  ));
```

The `AuthGuard` has to be registered as a Singleton in your GetIt serviceRegistry.

```
final GetIt serviceRegistry = GetIt.instance;

...

serviceRegistry.registerSingleton(AuthGuard(providerContainer))
```

Now you can access the instance of `AuthGuard` via `GetIt` like this:

```
AutoRoute(page: StarredRepoRoute.page, guards: [serviceRegistry<AuthGuard>()]),
```

Comment: but providercontainer not listening when state changes

Comment: is there any other problems by using uncontrolledproviderscope such as memory leaks or disposal problems?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem.  Then I changed my constructor implementation to:

```
Router extends _$Router {
 Router(this.authRouteGuard);
 final AuthRouteGuard authRouteGuard;
```

I then couldn't use my authRouteGuard as it couldn't be accessed in an initializer, further research led me to a closed issue for AutoRoute: https://github.com/Milad-Akarie/auto_route_library/issues/1469